# Android dmtracedump format

Tags: android, debugging, trace, callstack

I am looking at output of command:

```
dmtracedump -o com.example.android.notepad.trace
```

I understand that using dots they specify the hierarchy of calls. There is also specified actions "ent" and "xit" that shows whether it is enter-to or exit-from function. I thought that everything mentioned in output function has own "ent"  and  "xit" lines. But I have encountered on lines like this:

```
1 xit   1422199-com/example/android/notepad/NotesList.onCreate
```

without preceding "ent".

P.S. I need to determine all call that make an application

Answer (score 1):

I believe for this kind of analysis you are better off loading your trace in DDMS.  It's much easier to visualize the heirarchy of calls there since it's interactive.

Vogella a handy short introduction:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTools/article.html#tracewiew_eclipse

That said, dmtracedump's graph option (-g filename.png) is nice and perhaps you could use it to visualize your method calls.  Don't forget you need to install graphviz before running it.